# Unable to Build and Run Qt Examples

Tags: qt, build, qt-creator

I'm having no luck running the Qt examples with Qt Creator. I've tried three so far, but I have been unable to build and run any of them. Each one gives a different message, so I don't have anything specific pinpointing me to the problem.

Here's one error message:

> Starting
>   C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\widgets\mainwindows\build-application-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\application.exe...
>   The program has unexpectedly finished.
>   C:\Qt\Examples\Qt-5.5\widgets\mainwindows\build-application-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Debug\debug\application.exe
>   crashed

Another example: the `imageprovider` example displays a dialog that says:

> "Could not find the executable, please specify one."

Yet another example, the `plugandpaint` says:

> :-1: error: LNK1104: cannot open file 'pnp_basictoolsd.lib'

For the last one, I've attempted to load the `basictools` example and set a dependency, but the message is unchanged.

Any hints on how to debug this?

Comment: What is the first example ?

Answer (score 1):

1) Needs more info

2) `imageprovider` is a lib project, that's why you can't run it.

3) `plugandpaint` is a part of the `tools` project, it's not standalone. Open `tools.pro`instead.

Comment: Can you tell me an example that should work? I don't see a tools.pro when looking thought the examples. I can't get any example to load and run. I even tried re-installing. Where's the "Hello Qt"?

Comment: tools.pro is in the widgets\tools subdir of the Examples dir. That's strange that you can't run examples, there's **lots** of them, including some "hello". Plus the Tutorials. And the buttons are on the front page.

Comment: I can't even create my own hello world program. I pretty sure something is wrong with the install. The is very little in error messages and they are inconsistent with the #1 above the most common. I'm going re-install again for the 4th time. I wish there was a way to completely remove Qt, but clearly there isn't since I have to hand delete the C:\Qt folder each time. I can't tell what rubbish it is leaving to cause me trouble.

Comment: I only see 2 hello examples. "Hello GL2 Example." "Hello tr() Example." Not sure if these are sensible. I wish there was a basic "Hello Qt". Why Qt didn't think to include this is beyond me.

Comment: I just re-installed and now I make a new app and get a dialog that says "Unexpected CDB Exit
The CDB process terminated." I have no idea what a CDB. Maybe I should try the Visual Studio IDE. The Qt Creator IDE isn't helpful at all.

Comment: 1) CDB is the VS debugger. 2) You can create and run a basic GUI or console app by creating a new project and selecting an app type. 3) There's a bad interaction between Qt and your VS install, maybe you installed the wrong version. What is your VS version ? NB you can also install Qt / MinGW.